# several plots at once

Tags: plotting

I have several files what i would like to plot at once, they are .dat files and they have names as a numerical sequence from 1 to 4 (they are about a hundred but for the example 4 are ok) so i use

```
Do[ {p = Import["F:\P3 S2 L3\" <> ToString[i] <> "a.dat", "Table"]; 
     ListPlot[{p}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, All}}, 
              PlotStyle -> {Blue}]},
{i, 1, 4}]
```

but i dont have any result

suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `Do` does not produce any output, use `Table` instead.

Comment: @GregorioMartinez Can you plot even a *single* plot?

Comment: just put `Print@ListPlot..` in your loop if there are hundreds and you just want to display the plots individually.

Answer (score 2):

Create Data and export so we can have working files.

```
data = Table[{i, Sin[ a i]}, {a, 3}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
Export[StringJoin[ToString[#], "a.dat"], data[[#, All]]] & /@ 
  Range@Length[data];
```

Proceed to read the data now:

```
p = Import[StringJoin[ToString[#], "a.dat"]] & /@ Range[3];
```

Graph

```
ListPlot[Evaluate[p], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Graph the charts independently:

```
GraphicsColumn[
 ListPlot[p[[#, All]], Joined -> True, 
    PlotLabel -> StringJoin[ToString[#], "a.dat"]] & /@ 
  Range@Length@p]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i want the graphs to be independent each one in a different coordinated plane also, i already have the data in separated files.

Comment: If you look at the code you'll see it is reading separated files.(the first section of code creates separated files to use in the answer as no actual data has been provided.

Comment: Yes the files are different but all the plotted graphs are in the same coordinated plane since you used the p variable to call the data string. what i want is to have each sinusoidal in an independent figure Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Check the changes